# R webshot package enable cookies

Tags: r, facebook, cookies, phantomjs

I encountered a problem when using the [webshot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/vignettes/intro.html): I tried to login into facebook, because the screenshots I'd like to take are not possible without being loged in. The Login-Process documented below works, but there is an error that cookies should be allowed.

How to allow cookies?

```
library(webshot)
webshot("https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDeutschland/", file = "Test.png", 
eval = "casper.then(function() {
this.sendKeys('#login_form #email', 'XXX@XXX');
this.sendKeys('#login_form #pass', 'XXX');
this.click('#u_0_2');
this.wait(1000);
});"
)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/178 ?

Comment: thanks, but how to do this within R?

Comment: perhaps there's a nugget here: https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/175.  I don't know if [`decapitated`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/decapitated) wld be any better (I block all things facebook at a DNS/network/hosts and browser-level so I can't help test this particular issue) but I think headless Chrome will use existing user-cookies so it may work.